# Have any regulations been made under s22(2)(b) EA2010?

Tags: united-kingdom, discrimination, regulations

[Section 22(2)(b)](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2010/15/section/22?timeline=false) of the Equality Act 2010 allows for certain regulations. Have any been made thereunder?

Comment: It's hard to prove a negative, but I did [a search using those terms](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/secondary?text=%2222%282%29%28b%29%22%20%22equality%20act%202010%22). None of the results appeared to be regulations under that section of that act.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no regulations specifically made under s.22(2)(b).

Presumably that's because either "provision, criterion or practice" is too broad for the government to define with any precision, or they have decided to leave it up to the Employment Tribunal to assess each claim on its own particular set of circumstances as can be seen by my simplistic search returning [1,500+ potentially relevant hits](https://www.gov.uk/employment-tribunal-decisions?keywords=%22Equality+act+2010%22+%22disability%22+%22pcp%22+%22provision,+criterion+or+practice%22+&tribunal_decision_country%5B%5D=england-and-wales).

Comment: How do you know that no such regulations have ever been made?

Comment: Becaus they have not been referred to in Hansard, nor published by HMSO- either online or in print